# How to create visualisation on the fly using a script in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have some requirement where I need to create different visualization for different users which will differ very slightly on the query param. So, I am considering to create a script which will enable me to do this.Have anyone done this on Kibana 4. Some pointers on how to create visualization using query would be of great help.

I would also like to create Dashboards on the fly but that can wait till I get this one sorted out.

Comment: If you tell me how you get to know the parameters to be used, I can help you out. We use a java application to create charts as and when we start Elasticsearch service. You can modify the architecture for your own use :)

Comment: That is exactly what we want.We will have same type of graphs for all the users but with different set of filters.For some user say in x axis value of product will be P1 while for some other it will be P2. I can get the mapping of user1 : p1 and user2 :p2  but don't know how to proceed with creating the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go ahead with Java plugin (as mentioned in comments), here are the steps:

- Create different visualizations with different X-axis parameters. Visualizations are basically json strings so you can write a java code which changes the value of x aggregation based on the mapping that you have. Now each chart will have different ids.
- While you are creating a custom dashboard based on the user, check the mapping between user and the visualization and use the following command to add the visualization:
  client.prepareIndex(,"visualization",).setSource().execute();